# Error given while trying to compile python3 kivy app

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am not sure as to what this error is specifying. I give the full error log and also what we though may have been the issue yet it did not resolve the conflict.I am running Ubuntu 18.0.4 and doing this in a virtual environment.

```
    buildozer android debug deploy run
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Ensure build layout
    # Check configuration tokens
    # Preparing build
    # Check requirements for android
    # Run 'dpkg --version'
    # Cwd None
    Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
    This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
    later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
    # Search for Git (git)
    #  -> found at /usr/bin/git
    # Search for Cython (cython)
    #  -> found at /usr/bin/cython
    # Search for Java compiler (javac)
    #  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
    # Search for Java keytool (keytool)
    #  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
    # Install platform
    # Run 'pip install -q  "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5"       "jinja2" "six"'
    # Cwd None
    # Apache ANT found at /home/amazingratman/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
    # Android SDK found at /home/amazingratman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
    # Android NDK found at /home/amazingratman/Downloads/buildozer-master/.buildozer/android/platform
    # Check application requirements
    # Check garden requirements
    # Compile platform
    # Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,python3crystax --ndk-dir /home/amazingratman/Downloads/crystax-ndk-10.3.2-linux-x86_64/crystax-ndk-10.3.2/ --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/amazingratman/Desktop/python_stuff/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
    # Cwd /home/amazingratman/Desktop/python_stuff/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
```

Comment: Tried editing setup.py in both buidozer and buildozer-master from:
classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta', 'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',

Comment: to 

        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta', 'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6'
    ],

(We didn't have any particular reason to think this would work, it was just the only place we found "3.5")

Comment: Edit `buildozer.spec` and replace `log_level = 1` with `log_level = 2`. Retry `buildozer android debug` and post the new log. Please share your buildozer.spec.t

Comment: this was log_level = 2. and how can I post the whole contents of my build.spec file here?

Comment: Retry `buildozer android debug` and share the new log and `buildozer.spec` in Google Drive.